# Infinite loop of events

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates, observer-pattern

Let's say i have a simple form in c# (winforms) with two textboxes, one slider and an object called "the_volume".  An event (OnPropertyChanged) is sent whenever "the_volume.value" is changing.  How can i **CLEANLY** sync the four objects without causing an infinite loop?

- Without disconnecting the event listeners
- Without using a boolean to "guard"
- Without using databinding

small example: slider changes --> form::slider_changed --> the_volume is set --> form::the_volume_changed --> set the slider and texboxes values --> infinite loop...

My first instinct would be to avoid sending an event when the value does not changes but,

1- How can i know if the .net controls will do the same thing? (i.e. not triggering if the value is the same)

2- What bugs me is that there would be a "useless" setter call with this solution (set -> changed -> set -> stop loop)

Comment: afaik `TextBox` and `Slider` don't raise change events if there was no _real_ change (if the _new_ value is the same as the _old_ one). So there should be no infinite loop.

Comment: but is the extra "setter" call avoidable?

Comment: don't think it's a performance problem, so no need to avoid it. If you really want to avoid it, I'd suggest the "guard" boolean.

Comment: am i wrong to think that its not really MVC if each control has its own internal model ? wrong thread reply sorry

Comment: You are right, this isn't MVC. WinForms can use MVC or MVVM, but you have to build all the boilerplate code as it doesn't have the framework for it pre-built. It would take quite a bit of work and you'd have to overhaul much of the code. If this is a new project, just jump to WPF or UWA if you can and then you can move right into MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a WinForms question, but the way WPF does it should help you out. You can research INotifyPropertyChanged examples for more detail, but here's the basics:

```
//have a backing variable
private double _volume = 0;

//have a property
public double Volume
{
    get { return _volume; }
    set
    {
        // prevent any event firing if nothing changed
        if( _volume == value )
        {
            return;
        }

        // now we can set
        _volume = value;

        // something really changed, fire some event
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Now all your listeners will only be notified when something really did change. This type of check then fire can be applied to nearly any observer patter problem you have. This will prevent event looping as you stated in your question.

Comment: Yes this is a very good solution but what bugs me a little bit is the extra setter call

Comment: It's an if check and nothing gets set unless it needs to. You've mentioned an "extra setter call" in many of your comments. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by this. The over head of firing events is way more expensive than doing an if check or setting a value. Remember, memory has already been allocated to store your variable so setting the value will be about as minimal as you could have. The thing you want to avoid is redraws of the UI so preventing the event will be your best bet if performance is a concern.

Comment: Textbox1 setter -> changed event -> Textbox2 setter -> changed -> Textbox1 setter -> --end of loop--  But you are right its really nothing performance-wise

Comment: Ok, I see now. You are right, there is nothing you can do to avoid setting each Textbox. The reason being is their internal property of ".Text" can't be "bound" to the same object. This is why MVVM with binding is so helpful as it takes care of all the boilerplate code. You say Textbox2.Text and Textbox2.Text are both bound to ViewModel.Volume. Once Volume is changed, they are both updated. So, this problem has been solved using MVVM, but it's hard to inject that into WinForms. You have to create the boilerplate code or try to use some library to help. Or, move to WPF ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would have a single object that is responsible for routing the events. Let's call it `VolumeChangedEventRouter`. It would have its own "volume changed" event to which other entities could subscribe.

`VolumeChangedEventRouter` would subscribe to (or be subscribed to) each of your controls that could raise the "volume changed" event.

Then each of your controls would subscribe to (or would be subscribed to) the "volume changed" event of `VolumeChangedEventRouter`.

Then the `VolumeChangedEventRouter` would know the current volume, and thus it would know if it had changed and therefore whether to pass the event on to its subscribers.

You would probably use dependency injection to pass the `VolumeChangedEventRouter` to each of the classes that need to subscribe to its "volume changed" event. (You might even want to design `VolumeChangedEventRouter` so that it implements an interface which only contains the "volume changed" event, and pass that to the controls to minimise dependencies.)

It might even be possible to have a common `IVolumeChanger` interface which is implemented by `VolumeChangedEventRouter` AND all the controls, since they are all going to be raising "volume changed" events. That would reduce coupling quite a lot.

Comment: how can a TextBox control suscribe to an event?

Comment: @d08z You would need a controller for the TextBox - usually either the user control that contains it (for simple cases) or a separate controller class (for more complex cases). The controller would subscribe to the event and handle it appropriately.

Comment: Yes but there would still be additional useless setter calls.  However i dont think it matters performance-wise.

Comment: @d08z Yes, there would be useless (i.e. unprocessed) events being handled, but performance wise it would be negligible as you say. The important thing, however, is to ensure the routing logic is all in one place and not spread among several controls. One thing to watch out for, btw, is initialisation. If you're not careful, the initial volume setting my be ignored.